# Should FB.ActivateApp be manually called on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

We are using the latest available version of the Facebook SDK for Unity (v7.2.2)

One of the available APIs is ActivateApp ([FB.ActivateApp](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ActivateApp/)).

Should this method be called, specifically on iOS ?

Digging a bit into what's under the hood (the SDK is open source), I see that on iOS (in the file [FBUnityInterface.mm](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/blob/master/Facebook.Unity/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FBUnityInterface.mm)), there's the following code:

```
- (void)didBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

It looks like ActivateApp is being called automatically (whether i manually call it or not).

Should we call FB.ActivateApp when our app starts / resumes? won't this cause duplicate app activation reports ?

Comment: I would stick by what the Unity SDK documentation recommends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ActivateApp

Comment: Thanks i will look into that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

On iOS, ActivateApp seems to be called automatically in iOS native code.

Invoking the FB.ActivateApp method does nothing (see this code from IOSFacebook.cs):

```
 public override void ActivateApp(string appId)
 {
     IOSFacebook.IOSFBSettingsActivateApp(appId);
 }
```

The called method is simply empty:

```
private static void IOSFBSettingsActivateApp(string appId)
{
}
```

So, this seems to be taken care of automatically on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in here. We currently had a bug where when using UnityIAP, if a user bought a consumable IAP and quit the app before marking it Complete, they wouldn't get notified of the purchase on app restart.

In the end it came down to Facebook's automatic logging of IAP events in iOS (SDK >= 3.22). I think because it was adding a listener to the transaction queue before Unity.

I mention this because to turn on FB's auto logging of IAP, you need to set it in:

```
developers.facebook.com > App > Settings > Basic > iOS > iOS Only: Log In-App Purchase Events Automatically (Recommended)
```

Then call `ActivateApp()`. However, this is done automatically for you on iOS, so that only leaves the setting on the website or changing the code.

Long story short, if you're using Unity IAP and you're not getting purchase callbacks for incomplete purchases on iOS startup, it's either because of FB or another plugin adding a transaction queue listener (another user reported the possibility of AdMob). For us it was FB.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/iap-restorepurchase-on-ios-not-return-processpurchase-callback.392000/